# Perl: get the index of specific words in an array

Tags: arrays, perl

How can I get the index in an array that contain a word I am looking for.

Example:

```
$VAR1 = [
      'ID=T_03192',
      'Name=T_03192',
      'Alias=augustus_masked-2_Tcm_b3v06_scaf000585-processed-gene-0.22',
      'arth_ontology_term=GO:0006412,GO:0003735,GO:0005840',
      'arth_topblasthit=gi|1370630763|gb|PSN39892.1|60S ribosomal protein L12 [Blattella germanica]',
      'droso_ontology_term=GO:0003735,GO:0002181,GO:0000027,GO:0019843,GO:0022625',
      'droso_topblasthit=gi|17864452|ref|NP_524819.1|ribosomal protein L12, isoform A [Drosophila melanogaster]'
    ];
```

I would like the index that contain 'arth_topblasthit' so the result will be :

$VAR1[4]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is not totally the same: the other thread talk about exact match while my question look for index even if I have a partial match (like grep)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, as declared `$VAR1` as array reference earlier:

```
my $target = "arth_topblasthit";
my $idx = undef;

foreach ( 0 .. $#$VAR1 ) {
    if ( index ( $VAR1->[ $_ ], $target ) >= 0 ) {
        $idx = $_;
        last;
    }
}

## $idx is the targeting index, or undef if not found
```

**Note:** if we use

```
my $idx = undef;
foreach $idx ( ... ) {
    $idx = *something*
}

## now $idx = undef whatsoever
```

after the loop, $idx will become as before the loop.

Comment: I have this error:

Global symbol "$VAR1" requires explicit package name at tuto.pl line 164.

Comment: @user3819464 you have to declare before, like:

**my** $VAR1 = [
      'ID=T_03192',
      'Name=T_03192',
      'Alias=augustus_masked-2_Tcm_b3v06_scaf000585-processed-gene-0.22',
      'arth_ontology_term=GO:0006412,GO:0003735,GO:0005840',
      'arth_topblasthit=gi|1370630763|gb|PSN39892.1|60S ribosomal protein L12 [Blattella germanica]',
      'droso_ontology_term=GO:0003735,GO:0002181,GO:0000027,GO:0019843,GO:0022625',
      'droso_topblasthit=gi|17864452|ref|NP_524819.1|ribosomal protein L12, isoform A [Drosophila melanogaster]'
    ];

Comment: Ahh ok I understand now but I have an array under this form: @VAR1 = ('ID, ...)

Comment: @user3819464 if you declare as array `@VAR1`, the code changes a bit as the syntax issue, like `@array` is `$arrayref`, `$#array` is `$#$arrayref`, `$array[0]` is `$arrayref->[0]`